Is the mapping anima functor a functor of infinity-categories?
Are two definitions of compact objects equivalent?
We refer to two definitions of compact objects in  "Higher Topos Theory" (HTT) by Lurie and "Sheaves on Manifolds" (KNP) by Krause, Nicolaus, and Putzstuck.
We just consider ($\omega$-)compact objects.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category, and let $X$ be an object of $\mathcal{C}$.
We let $j : \mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathrm{An})$ denote the covariant Yoneda embedding.
In HTT, $X$ is compact if the functor $j(X) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{An}$ preserves filtered colimits.
In KNP, $X$ is compact if the mapping anima functor $\mathrm{Map}(X,-)$ commutes with colimits. i.e. $\mathrm{colim}_i\mathrm{Map}(X,Y_i) \to \mathrm{Map}(X,\mathrm{colim}_iY_i)$ is an equivalence for any filtered diagram $Y : I \to \mathcal{C}$.
My questions are that

Is the mapping anima functor defined as a functor of $\infty$-categories?

Moreover, Is the covariant Yoneda embedding $j(X)$ equivalent to $\mathrm{Map}(X,-)$ as a functor?

I am not sure how to define the functor $\mathrm{Map}(X,-)$.
(Can we define using the twisted arrow category?)
I think $j(X)(Y)$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Map}(X,Y)$ objectwise.

Comparing with HTT, KNP's definition is clear and one-categorical.
In fact, some proofs in KNP is one-categorical (for example, Lemma 2.1.3 (2)).
Are these proofs rigorous in the setting of $\infty$-categories?


Edit After Stahl, Tim, Georg's comments, I summarized answers to my questions. Thanks!
First, I used the symbol $j$ of the covariant Yoneda embedding as defined  in HTT.
(2) I found Remark.5.3.5.2 in HTT, j(X) classifies the right fibration $\mathcal{C}_{/X} \to \mathcal{C}$, so $\mathrm{Map}(X,-)$ is equivalent to $j(X)$ as a functor. This also solves (1) and (3).
However, I cannot find the functor $j$ defined in HTT, is equivalent to $\mathrm{Map}(-,-)$. It may be discussed in Higher Algebra...
(4) As mentioned in Tim's comment, some proofs in KNP, it should be rigorous, but (maybe) these are not rigorous, right?

You might find this helpful.

There are several questions here. The answer to each of them is "yes, you can look this up in HTT". The answer to the first question is "yes, these two definitions are literally the same". Re: Lemma 2.1.3 in KNP, they cite Lurie for part (i). That's rigorous. Their "sanity check" and parenthetical comment are not rigorous. The string of natural isomorphisms they use for part (ii) should be rigorous, though it might be a pain to look up precise justifications in HTT. As with 1-cats, It might also be a pain to check that the composite map is homotopic to the canonical one, but should be doable.

Tim basically answered your question, but let me add: The way Lurie (and others) deal with the yoneda embedding is by abusing the Straightening/Unstraightening equivalence. The gist is that the functor $Map(X,-)$ corresponds to the cocartesion fibration $C_{X/} \rightarrow C$, and the bifunctor $Map(-,-)$ corresponds to $Tw(C) \rightarrow C^{op} \times C$, where $Tw(C)$ is the twisted arrow category. All of this is developed in HTT. (As a more digestible resource I can recommend the notes of Fabian Hebestreit)

Thanks everyone! I added some comments.
